# Fill in color of TImage content

Tags: user-interface, colors, c++builder, c++builder-6, timage

I'm using Borland C++Builder 6.

I would like to use the `TImage` component and just fill its content in a specific color (assume, black) - how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

be more specific your text is a bit vague

Sorry I do not use `TImage` component but its high likely your `TImage` has `Canvas` so you can use GDI try something like:

```
img->Canvas->Brush->Color=clBlack;
img->Canvas->Brush->Style=bsSolid;
img->Canvas->FillRect(TRect(0,0,img->Width,img->Height));
```

- where `img` is your TImage component name
- there may be issues with `Update` similar to `TPanintbox`
- so if you got flicker call `img->Update();` or `img->Refresh/Repaint...` before this or move the rendering to different event like `img->OnPaint` ...
- also you can use `ClientWidth,ClientHeight` if `TImage` has them (not all components does)

Comment: Thanks you for you support!

Comment: The `TImage::Canvas` property is only valid when the `TImage` is holding a `TBitmap` graphic. That is what you would actually be drawing on, as `TImage::Canvas` simply returns the `TImage::Picture::Bitmap::Canvas` pointer. If all you want to do is display a square/rectangle in a single color, you could assign a 1x1 pixel `TBitmap` to the `TImage`, making sure the `TImage::Stretch` property is set to true. Otherwise, use a `TPaintBox` instead and just `FillRect()` the `TPaintBox::Canvas` in the `TPaintBox::OnPaint` event.